# How to work with the reference type in firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following `Firestore` document structure:

[image]

This is the output

[image]

As you can see the `stop` which is under `12:00PM` is showing under the `1:00PM`. I think it is due to `asynchronous` request. So how I can handle it?

Actually first of all I'm getting the document then get the `keys` of departure which are `times` then get the `stops` array of that time, now again send the request to get the stop name and city.

Here is the code which I'm using to fetch the time and all the stops of that time.

```
db.collection(DBMeta.COLLECTION_ROUTE)
.document(routeIntent.getId())
.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        Route route = null;
        if(documentSnapshot!=null)
        route = documentSnapshot.toObject(Route.class);
        if(route != null){
            if(route.getDeparture() != null){
                String[] departures = route.getDeparture().keySet().toArray(new String[route.getDeparture().keySet().size()]);
                for(String time : departures){
                    Object object = route.getDeparture().get(time).get(DBMeta.DOCUMENT_ROUTE_STOPS);
                    ArrayList<DocumentReference> stops = (ArrayList<DocumentReference>)object;
                    departureLayout.addView(timeTextView(time));
                    for(DocumentReference stop : stops){
                        stop.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                final String bussStop = documentSnapshot.getString(DBMeta.DOCUMENT_STOP_NAME);
                                DocumentReference doc = documentSnapshot.getDocumentReference(DBMeta.DOCUMENT_STOP_CITY);
                                if(doc != null){
                                    doc.get()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                            String cityAbbrev = documentSnapshot.getString(DBMeta.DOCUMENT_CITY_ABBREV);
                                            departureLayout.addView(stopTextView(bussStop + " - " + cityAbbrev));
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: use Async tasks to handle,I doubt it to be from this

Comment: Example could save my a lot of time. -_-

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46145191/9025311

Comment: @D.'s that is different problem. they are fetching behind the scene only from one document, but I need to fetch from the multiple documents due to reference.

Comment: this is a good question for @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: According to your document strcuture, what is the output that you want to get?

Comment: @AlexMamo as you can see I have added the output screenshot too, the stops are adding under the 1:00PM, but one should be under 12:00PM

Comment: To understand better, `/stops/IQdng...` is `Jail Chowk - GRT`, right?

Comment: No that is `ByPass - GRW`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
db.collection(DBMeta.COLLECTION_ROUTE).document(routeIntent.getId()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                Map<String, Object> departureMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("departure");
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : departureMap.entrySet()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, entry.getKey());
                    Map<String, Object> innerMap = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : innerMap.entrySet()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output will be:

```
12:00 PM
ByPass - GRW
1:00 PM
Jail Chowk - GRT
```

Don't use an `addSnapshotListener` unless you need to get realtime updates.

Comment: There is a reference to each stop, then how ti could be possible to get the Stop name and City Abbreviation without sending new request to firestore?

Comment: You cannot without sending new request to Firestore.  But as I answered in this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190130/how-to-use-wheretoequal-on-sub-object-array-with-unknown-field/50227432)**, you might consider changing the database structure so you can query based on element that exist within a map and display the data more easily.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations regarding this issue?